# Orangehrm:Create new menu function

Tags: symfony, orangehrm

I am new to symfony framework. Now I am customizing orangehrm to suit certain new requirements.

For example: Similar to Admin>Qualifications>skills menu, I need to create Admin>Qualifications>Category.I have made the menu modifications by editing index.php file.

The functionality for this new page is similar to 'Skill' page.But we need to use different database table. Orangehrm uses doctrine for database related operation. I am not at all familiar with doctrine either.

Could someone please give the instructions for implementing 'Admin>Qualifications>Category' function? It is very urgent and I think the process is also very simple (not sure).

Comment: I also have to do something like you need. Did you find any solution @Misty If yes then please post your own answer.

Comment: follow this link http://vizteck.com/blog/6-steps-how-write-new-module-orange-hrm/

Answer (score 1):

First you have to add your menu in database then create classes in your specific module.

Step 1: Check in which module do you want to add your menu.
        module list is in ohrm_module table.

Step 2: Check under what user roll you want to add menu.
        user roll is in ohrm_user_role.

Step 3: Add Screen on bases of module (step 1).
        insert data into ohrm_screen

step 4: Add Menu Item on bases of Screen (step 3).
        insert into ohrm_menu_item

Step 5: Assign screen to user on bases of user roll (step 2) and screen (step 3).
        insert into ohrm_user_role_screen

Step 6: Logout and login again. New menu will be there.

Step 7: Go to your plugin folder and create your controller in action folder like this
        class YourLinkNameAction extends sfAction {
        //SANI: Start all coding in execute method
        } 
Step 8: Create your View in template folder like this
        YourLinkNameSuccess.php

That's all